# Array will not display data, only getting undefined, undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have been struggling with F--king arrays and objects and they will not display to browser.

I have used a constructor to build the array and then pushed it to the array inventory.
I've been fiddling with this for days and I just don't get it.
This keeps stopping me in all my projects, the minute I try to access an array I get undefined
All I've ever gotten is Undefined. I really don't understand what i've done wrong.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend checking out [mcve] to learn more about how to minimize the code posted to best assist in receiving assistance.

Comment: In JavaScript, [arrays are zero-indexed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). That means your bounds-check should [use `i < length` instead of `i <= length`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74830337/13561410).

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue "getting undefined, undefined"? Maybe include an error log?

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop says:

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= inventory.length; i++)
```

But that will go past the last item in the array, because the last item in the array will have the index `inventory.length-1` and not `inventory.length`.

Instead, do:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++)
```

Comment: I thought <= is equal too or less than ? however it doesnt fix my undefined undefined problem

Comment: @CTR it is. Which means if you have an array of 3 items, `i` will have the values 0,1,2,3 during the loop. But it should only have the values 0,1,2 during the loop.

Comment: @CTR please be specific about what buttons to press in your example in order to recreate the undefined problem

Comment: I have added an image to explain the problem I'm having

Comment: @CTR I don't see that when I load your code example, as long as the `<` change is made in the for loop. Do I need to push any buttons to see what you're seeing?

Comment: No, it just just load the table, I"m not sure if you can see the image I posted. Its no longer in my post now. I might just make a new question because this just isnt clear.

Comment: @CTR I saw your image. But when I load your code (and make the <= to < change) I don't see undefined. So either your screenshot is of different code, or you are pushing some buttons to make the table appear with undefined in it

Comment: Can I email it to you ?

Comment: @CTR no, just edit your question and use the "HTML/Javascript snippet" button to upload a version of your code that we will be able to see and diagnose.

Comment: I've been trying too, it's telling me it isnt formated correctly, I correct it and its still complaining. So at this point I'm to irritated to function.